# Parsing Twitter API Datestamp

Tags: php, javascript, time, twitter, parsing

I'm using the twitter API to return a list of status updates and the times they were created. It's returning the creation date in the following format:

> Fri Apr 09 12:53:54 +0000 2010

What's the simplest way (with PHP or Javascript) to format this like 09-04-2010?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`strtotime("dateString");` gets it into the native PHP date format, then you can work with the `date()` function to get it printed out how you'd like it.

Comment: That sounds good thanks, 
$time = strtotime($phrase->created_at);           echo $time;
is giving me it like this... 1270817634. How do I use the date() function with that?

Comment: Ah wait, got it working. date("jS F Y", $time) gives me 9th April 2010.
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the date parsing in PHP is pretty well formed. Note that strtotime will accept ALMOST anything you throw into it. It's expensive but quite powerful.

Comment: when i use echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("Wed Nov 19 07:08:49 +0000 2014")) , php print time as 2014-11-19 08:08:49. It is one hour ahead , time in original string is 07:08:49 and in converted string it it 08:08:49. I don't know why is that but its not working for me.

Comment: It convert date correctly only when we remove +0000 part.

Answer (score 49):

Cross-browser, time-zone-aware parsing via JavaScript:

```
var s = "Fri Apr 09 12:53:54 +0000 2010";

var date = new Date(
    s.replace(/^\w+ (\w+) (\d+) ([\d:]+) \+0000 (\d+)$/,
        "$1 $2 $4 $3 UTC"));
```

Tested on IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Great answer.  Why did Twitter settle on this horrible date format?

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript can parse that date if you remove the `+0000` from the string:

```
var dStr = "Fri Apr 09 12:53:54 +0000 2010";
dStr = dStr.replace("+0000 ", "") + " UTC";
var d = new Date(dStr);
```

Chrome -- and I suspect some other non IE browsers -- can actually parse it with the `+0000` present in the string, but you may as well remove it for interoperability.

PHP can parse the date with strtotime:

```
strtotime("Fri Apr 09 12:53:54 +0000 2010");
```

Comment: thanks, I went with the strtotime option. However your Javascript example just answered another question I had, thanks!

Comment: However, the original date string is probably in UTC (and hence the +0000). `new Date()` will parse it in the local time zone.

Comment: This gets parsed in the correct time zone: `dStr = dStr.replace("+0000 ", "") + " GMT";`

Comment: @Ates Goral: Thanks for your corrections, I had forgotten that ECMAScript implementations parse dates in the local timezone if one is omitted.

Comment: @Andy E's head: We're not quite done yet :( Safari doesn't like this but it works fine on IE, FF, Opera and Chrome.

Comment: @Ates Goral: That seems very odd, given that both Safari and Chrome use the same engine (WebKit).  Can Safari parse it with the `+0000` in? If it works OK like that then the solution would be to try and create the `Date()` before the replace and fall back to the str replace if that date is NaN.

Comment: I agree; that's weird. Doing things more explicitly seems to be the only way... I've posted my approach as a separate answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611415/parsing-twitter-api-datestamp/2766516#2766516

Comment: @Andy E's head: Well Safari and Chrome both use WebKit for rendering HTML but Safari uses SquirrelFish/Nitro and Chrome uses V8 for executing Javascript. That should be the reason for the difference in behaviour.

Comment: @paracycle: I wasn't aware of that (I thought V8 was part of WebKit), thanks for clarifying. @Ates Goral: +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is date format for Twitter API:

```
Sat Jan 19 20:38:06 +0000 2013
"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
```

Comment: What is the meaning of "Z" here ? Is it zone ? +0000 ? What will be the time in IST ? GMT +5:30

Comment: @SANDHYALALKUMAR thats RFC 822 Timezone // https://gist.github.com/romaonthego/5138532

Answer (score 3):

Javascript. As @Andy pointed out, is going to be a bitch when it comes to IE. So it's best to rely on a library that does it consistently. [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) seems like a nice library.

Once the library is added, you would parse and format it as:

```
var date = Date.parse("Fri Apr 09 12:53:54 +0000 2010");
var formatted = date.toString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

In PHP you can use the date functions or the DateTime class to do the same (available since PHP 5.2.0):

```
$date = new DateTime("Fri Apr 09 12:53:54 +0000 2010");
echo $date->format("d-m-Y"); // 09-04-2010
```

Comment: This gives `NaN` in Internet Explorer, although it works in Chrome.  IE struggles with the `+0000`.

Comment: thanks for the tip Andy. it's best to go server side, or use a date parsing library such a datejs

Comment: There's also a good jQuery PHPDate library available (via google)

Comment: PHPDate looks like a nice plugin for date handling. Like the way how they setup the "Try me" demos for different formats on the front page.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, in **Java** it is:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date d = sdf.parse(dateAsString);

sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String s = sdf.format(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

And in **Swift**:

```swift
let dateString = "Fri Apr 09 12:53:54 +0000 2010"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```