# twitter time date stamp -Which time zone is it?

Tags: twitter

I read in a post at stackoverflow about the time date stamp for tweets that

> the timezone of each tweet is automatically converted to the local timezone. If you need UTC, you can use the `.ToUniversalTime()` method, for example:
>   `myTweet.CreatedDate.ToUniversalTime();`

I wanted to know, when I download a tweet from Twitter's streaming API, what is the time zone. In the answer above they wrote that it is converted to the local timezone. I was not sure if that is the local zone of me (the person downloading the tweet stream) or of the person sending the tweet or of some ISP or somewhere else. Could anyone clarify this?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 15):

The API stores and returns dates and times in GMT to avoid issues with clock changes.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217056/twitter-timezone-created-at-utc-time-values-to-calculate-what-time-zone-the-u), you can use the `utc_offset` property of the user object (which is returned with the tweet) to calculate the time relative to the user's timezone.

Comment: Thanks, I did not do the programming myself but I suppose that there was no transformation of the date and time and that I can assume that my times are GMT therefore

Comment: @Duck url is dead