# How to reliably determine time zone for a user from the Twitter API?

Tags: datetime, twitter, timezone

When getting information from Twitter's API for a user, they provide two fields related to the user's time zone:

```
utc_offset: -14400,
time_zone: "Indiana (East)"
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't tell the full story because I don't know if that UTC offset was calculated during standard time or daylight savings time. After dividing by 3600 seconds, I get -4 hours, which is valid during the summer months, but in the winter the correct value would be -5 hours.

If the value was ALWAYS determined by the daylight savings time value then I could write an algorithm for that, however after some searching on the subject I've seen several pasted outputs that contradict that assumption. (as a quick example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6218781) shows his/her offset as -21600 and then he/she says he/she is on central time, which if calculated during daylight savings time would be -18000).

It would make sense to me that the value would be calculated as of Jan 1 and the several pasted outputs I've found online fall into that category, but my own Twitter account shows the values listed above for which this assumption is invalid. My next thought was maybe it was calculated at the time I created my account, but then that seems erroneous as well because I can change my time zone at any later point (and even so, I created my account in November when I would have been on standard and not daylight time!).

My last thought was that maybe the value is being calculated by the date of the API request. This makes a lot of sense and the Twitter accounts I own all seem to validate this. BUT, [the SA question I linked to earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6218781) shows that the person answered the question on June 2nd, which is daylight savings time and his/her value of -21600 reflects a standard time for the Central time zone.

Anyone out there solve this problem? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter's front end uses Ruby on Rails.  If you go to your own twitter account settings and look at the possible options for time zones (view source on the dropdown list), you will find that they match up with those provided by `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`, shown in [this documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html).  Although there appears to be some zones understood by Rails that Twitter has omitted, all of the Twitter zone key names are in that list.

I have asked Twitter to use standard time zone names in the future, [in this developer request.](https://twittercommunity.com/t/please-use-standard-time-zone-identifiers/12081)

Why does Rails limit this list and use their own key values?  Who knows.  I have asked before, and gotten very little response.  [Read here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubyonrails-talk/3oUESnDSR6A/AC5BlUh1JREJ).

But you can certainly use their mapping dictionary to turn the `time_zone` value into a standard IANA time zone identifier.  For example:

- `"Indiana (East)"` => `"America/Indiana/Indianapolis"`
- `"Central Time (US & Canada)"` => `"America/Chicago"`

This can be found in the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html), and in the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb).  (Scroll down to `MAPPING`.)

Then you can use any standard IANA/Olson/TZDB implementation you wish.  They exist for just about every language and platform.  For further details, see the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  If you need help with a specific implementation, you'll need to expand your question to tell us what language you are using and what you have tried so far.  (Or consider asking a new question about just that part of it.)

In regards to the `utc_offset` field, twitter does not make it clear what basis they use to calculate it.  My guess is that it is the user's *current* offset, based on the time that you call the API.

**Update 1**

I have added support for converting Rails time zone names to both IANA and Windows standard time zone identifiers in my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library for .NET.  If you are using .NET, you can use this library to simplify your conversions and stay on top of updates more easily.

**Update 2**

Twitter's API [now returns the time zone](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-settings) in this format:

```
"time_zone": {
    "name": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
    "tzinfo_name": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "utc_offset": -28800
},
```

Use the `tzinfo_name` field.  Done. :)