# Convert string to timestamp in PHP using strtotime

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Trying to change string like

```
Tue Jun 28 15:24:51 +0000 2011
```

to php unix time.

Found this [Parsing Twitter API Datestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611415/parsing-twitter-api-datestamp) but **strtotime** returns -1 for me.

```
echo strtotime('Fri Apr 09 12:53:54 +0000 2010');
```

Any ideas? Probably hosting problems?

Thanks

This dinosaurs use PHP 4.4.9, so code doesn't work.
I added

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
```

and it starts to work:)

Comment: Which PHP version do you run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = strtotime('Fri Apr 09 12:53:54 +0000 2010');
echo date('d/m/Y',$date);
echo $date;
```

Works for me. Check the the PHP version compability:
[strtotime() api](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)