# Querying date range if its saved as a string in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, php, json, mongodb, twitter

Is it even possible (tho i doubt) to query a date range in PHP from MongoDB if I have this field saved as a string? If not, is there a way to do so? I couldn't change the data either since its from Twitter Streaming API. I'm using PHP for the back-end in my website. NodeJS with Mongoose in collecting and storing in MongoDB

```
{
    "created_at": "Fri Aug 04 05:42:03 +0000 2017"
}
```

Comment: yes it is possible. query wil see the range of start date and end date. then you get the value of in between.

Comment: @Aman I've read somewhere (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611415/parsing-twitter-api-datestamp/2611420#2611420) that this format will not work. So I have to convert it in PHP using this snippet `strtotime("Fri Aug 04 05:42:03 +0000 2017")`. I just wanted to clarify if you need to entirely replace all of the "created_at" in the MongoDB or just parse it in PHP without touching the documents inside the DB? Only have 41 reps so I couldn't comment in his post :)