# Dart parse date with +0000

Tags: date, flutter, dart, dateformatter

I am using the Twitter api for getting tweets in a Flutte App.
The api returns a formatted date like this:

`Wed Jun 12 00:08:35 +0000 2019`

```
  DateTime formatTwitterDate() {
    final format = DateFormat('EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss +0000 yyyy'); //todo failed to resolve +0000
    return format.parse(this);
  }
```

This is the only formatter I got working. How can I support +0000?

Comment: if it's always `+0000` remove it from the string by using regex or split by space , remove then join by space

Comment: +0000 indicates the timezone so you don't want to remove this

Comment: Look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611415/parsing-twitter-api-datestamp this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2766516/8608146

Comment: you can remove as @PhaniRithvij suggested and then add them in time.

Comment: Even though `DateFormat` documents the `Z` formatter for timezone offsets, it apparently is not implemented (see [issue #19](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/19), [issue #74](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/74), [issue #264](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/264)).

Answer (score 0):

Used this javascript implementation and transformed it to a DartExtension

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2611438/5115254

```
extension StringToDateTime on String {
  DateTime formatTwitterDate() {
    final newDateString = '${replaceAll('+0000 ', '')} UTC';
    final format = DateFormat('EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy Z');
    return format.parse(newDateString);
  }
}
```

Comment: does this add time base on location as you mention in comment ? example +0010 then does it add 10 minutes in time ?

Answer (score 0):

Porting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2766516/8608146) answer to dart

```dart
  var s = "Fri Apr 09 12:53:54 +0000 2010";
  print(s);

  final newString =
      s.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'\w+ (\w+) (\d+) ([\d:]+) \+0000 (\d+)'), (m) {
    return "${m[1]} ${m[2]} ${m[4]} ${m[3]} UTC";
  });
  print(newString);
```